# Como posso salvar o máximo valor obtido em rowCount?

Tags: php

Como faço a logica para que só atualizar minha variável quando o valor do RowCount for o maior já obtido?

Exemplo:
Realizei a consulta sql e retornou 15 registro, salvei 15 na variável `$maximo`então realizei outra consulta e retornou 12 então não atualizo a variável `$maximo`, realizei uma terceira consulta e retornou 17 então ai atualizo a variável `$maximo` para 17.

Condigo atual:

```
static function playeronline($pdoG)
{
    try {
        $playeronline = $pdoG->prepare("SELECT login FROM u_hero WHERE login = 1");
        $playeronline->execute();

        $numeroonline = $playeronline->rowCount();
        $numeroonline = $numeroonline * 1.3;
        $numeroonline = round($numeroonline);

        return $numeroonline;



    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Não estou sabendo iniciar a variavel maximo.

Comment: Só verificar se o valor retornado é maior que o que você tem na variavel `$maximo`, mas, tem como colocar seu código?

Comment: Então não sei como iniciar a variável máximo, vou alterar e colocar o codigo atual.

Answer (score 0):

Há algumas coisas a se considerar. Os multiplos acessos à função `playeronline()` vão ser feitos na mesma requisição http, ou em diferentes requesições de diferentes usuários? Vamos ver um exemplo para cada caso.

### Multiplos acessos na mesma requisição

```
<?php
$maximo = 0;

//um loop para simular varias chamadas à função `playeronline`
for($i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    $players = playeronline(databaseConnection);
    if($players > $maximo){
        $maximo = $players;
    }
}

//depois faça alguma coisa com a variavel $maximo

static function playeronline($pdoG)
{
    try {
        $playeronline = $pdoG->prepare("SELECT login FROM u_hero WHERE login = 1");
        $playeronline->execute();

        $numeroonline = $playeronline->rowCount();
        $numeroonline = $numeroonline * 1.3;
        $numeroonline = round($numeroonline);

        return $numeroonline;



    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

### Multiplos acessos em diferentes requisições

Aqui você pode utilizar a variavel global `$_SESSION` para persirtir dados entre requisições http (de páginas) distintas. Então fica:

```
<?php
//inicializa o uso de sessão (retire se você já estiver incluindo isso)
session_start();

//inicializa $_SESSION['maximo'] com 0 no primeiro acesso
if(!isset($_SESSION['maximo'])){
    $_SESSION['maximo'] = 0;
}

$players = playeronline(databaseConnection);

if($players > $_SESSION['maximo']){
    $_SESSION['maximo'] = $players;
}

//depois faça alguma coisa com a variavel $maximo

static function playeronline($pdoG)
{
    try {
        $playeronline = $pdoG->prepare("SELECT login FROM u_hero WHERE login = 1");
        $playeronline->execute();

        $numeroonline = $playeronline->rowCount();
        $numeroonline = $numeroonline * 1.3;
        $numeroonline = round($numeroonline);

        return $numeroonline;



    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sé eu inicializar a variável $maximo = 0; fora da function toda vez que eu chamar o arquivo ele não vai zerar não?

Comment: Sim vai zerar. Nesse caso você deve utilizar o segundo exemplo, onde a variavel `$_SESSION[$maximo]` só vai ser inicializada na primeira inclusão (chamada do arquivo).

Comment: mais a session não so inicializa por cada acesso ao site? tipo se um usuário entrar? ou o servidor por si só já inicia um session?

Comment: A session é inicializada quando um usuario acessar o site (primeiro acesso), até que a sessão seja encerrada, os dados não são apagados entre as requisições. Voltando ao seu caso, cada usuario no primeiro acesso vai ter `$_SESSION['maximo']` inicializada com 0, mas nos acessos posteriores será "lembrada" o ultimo valor de rowCount.

Comment: Mas então se um usuário nunca acessou meu site o máximo seria 0 e não seria proveitoso já que quero que os usuarios saibam qual foi a maior quantidade de acessos.

Comment: Se ele nunca acessou seu site (nunca viu seu site) o valor zero não se aplica. Sempre que houver um acesso (primeiro) o valor deixara de ser zero. Mas me surgiu uma duvida, me parece que você faz o calculo com base em uma consulta sql, e aparentemente manter isso em sessão parece ser desnecessario. Isso procede?

Comment: Sim por que sempre que alguem entra realizo a consulta de plays online e tenho que manter registrado um valor maximo, vou fazer um inserte e ficar consultando o valor e atualizar ele se for maior que o já obtido, foi a solução.